# Как принудительно увеличивать высоту клавиатуры?

Tags: java, android

Есть исходник клавиатуры https://github.com/maihannijat/AndroidKeyboard
Проблема в том что когда происходит вывод слов из словаря, то поле с словарем налаживается на поле ввода. А в приложение ютуб вообще не выводит слова, то есть не выводит drawable.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод самого словаря происходит в классе **SoftKeyboard**, в методе **setSuggestions**.

```
public void setSuggestions(List<String> suggestions, boolean completions,
                               boolean typedWordValid) {
        if (suggestions != null && suggestions.size() > 0) {
            setCandidatesViewShown(true);
        } else if (isExtractViewShown()) {
            setCandidatesViewShown(true);
        } else {
            setCandidatesViewShown(false);
        }
        if (mCandidateView != null) {
            mCandidateView.setSuggestions(suggestions, completions, typedWordValid);
        }
    }
```

Вот класс LatinoKeybord который наследует класс Keyboard

```
class LatinKeyboard extends Keyboard {
    private Key mEnterKey;
    private Key mSpaceKey;
    /**
     * Stores the current state of the mode change key. Its width will be dynamically updated to
     * match the region of {@link #mModeChangeKey} when {@link #mModeChangeKey} becomes invisible.
     */
    private Key mModeChangeKey;
    /**
     * Stores the current state of the language switch key (a.k.a. globe key). This should be
     * visible while
     * returns true. When this key becomes invisible, its width will be shrunk to zero.
     */
    private Key mLanguageSwitchKey;
    /**
     * Stores the size and other ic_information_48 of {@link #mModeChangeKey} when
     * {@link #mLanguageSwitchKey} is visible. This should be immutable and will be used only as a
     * reference size when the visibility of {@link #mLanguageSwitchKey} is changed.
     */
    private Key mSavedModeChangeKey;
    /**
     * Stores the size and other ic_information_48 of {@link #mLanguageSwitchKey} when it is visible.
     * This should be immutable and will be used only as a reference size when the visibility of
     * {@link #mLanguageSwitchKey} is changed.
     */
    private Key mSavedLanguageSwitchKey;

    LatinKeyboard(Context context, int xmlLayoutResId) {
        super(context, xmlLayoutResId);
    }
    public LatinKeyboard(Context context, int layoutTemplateResId,
                         CharSequence characters, int columns, int horizontalPadding) {
        super(context, layoutTemplateResId, characters, columns, horizontalPadding);
    }
    @Override
    protected Key createKeyFromXml(Resources res, Row parent, int x, int y,
                                   XmlResourceParser parser) {
        Key key = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        if (key.codes[0] == 10) {
            mEnterKey = key;
        } else if (key.codes[0] == ' ') {
            mSpaceKey = key;
        } else if (key.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE) {
            mModeChangeKey = key;
            mSavedModeChangeKey = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        } else if (key.codes[0] == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH) {
            mLanguageSwitchKey = key;
            mSavedLanguageSwitchKey = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        }
        return key;
    }
    /**
     * Dynamically change the visibility of the language switch key (a.k.a. globe key).
     * @param visible True if the language switch key should be visible.
     */
    void setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            // The language switch key should be visible. Restore the size of the mode change key
            // and language switch key using the saved layout.
            mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width;
            mModeChangeKey.x = mSavedModeChangeKey.x;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.width = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.icon;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview;
        } else {
            // The language switch key should be hidden. Change the width of the mode change key
            // to fill the space of the language key so that the user will not see any strange gap.
            mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width + mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.width = 0;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = null;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = null;
        }
    }
    /**
     * This looks at the ime options given by the current editor, to set the
     * appropriate label on the keyboard's enter key (if it has one).
     */
    void setImeOptions(Resources res, int options) {
        if (mEnterKey == null) {
            return;
        }
        switch (options&(EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_go_key);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_next_key);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                mEnterKey.icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_search_black);
                mEnterKey.label = null;
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_send_key);
                break;
            default:
                mEnterKey.icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black);
                mEnterKey.label = null;
                break;
        }
    }
    void setSpaceIcon(final Drawable icon) {
        if (mSpaceKey != null) {
            mSpaceKey.icon = icon;
        }
    }
    private static class LatinKey extends Key {

        LatinKey(Resources res, Row parent, int x, int y,
                 XmlResourceParser parser) {
            super(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        }

        /**
         * Overriding this method so that we can reduce the target area for the key that
         * closes the keyboard.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isInside(int x, int y) {
            return super.isInside(x, codes[0] == KEYCODE_CANCEL ? y - 10 : y);
        }
    }


}
```

Создал ещё один Row в файле клавиатуры, но как мне вывести там слова а не в drawable или же поместить сам drawable в созданный Row?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]